# I have a movie website, and I am trying to display the Genres (total of 20) in Bootstrap structure 4 cols wide

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

There 20 genres, and I would like to make them 5 rows, and 4 columns using a php 7 loop (while, for, foreach) and display using Bootstrap. I cannot seem to figure out the php code to achieve that. I have made several attempts at this, but just cannot seem to get it right.

Desired Results: - to repeat X times in a horizontal row fashion

`<div class="row">`

`<div class="col-sm-3">content</div>`

`<div class="col-sm-3">content</div>`

`<div class="col-sm-3">content</div>`

`<div class="col-sm-3">content</div>`

`</div>`

```
while($name=$result->fetch_assoc()){ 

    foreach(array_chunk($name, 4) as $$nameRow) {
        echo '<div class="row">';
            foreach($nameRow as $genreName) {
                echo "<div class='col-sm-3'>$genreName</div>";
            }
        echo '</div>'
    }
    }
```

I have also tried but get an error with &&:

```
$result->data_seek(0);
    $n = 0;
    echo '<div class="row">';
    while($name=$result->fetch_assoc()){ 

    $name = round($name["name"] + 500, 2);
    $fullName= "<a href='".$site."/genre-search/?Gtype=".$name."' title='Click to view titles in Genre ".$name."!'><span style='font-family: Maven Pro; font-size: 18px;'>".$name."</span></a>";
    if($n%4 == && $n =! 0) {
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="row">';
        echo '<div class="col-sm-3">' . $fullName . '</div>';
        $n = 1;
    } else {
        echo '<div class="col-sm-3">' . $fullName . '</div>';
        $n++;
    }
    }
    echo '</div>';
```

Any and all guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: show us the php code you attempted.

Comment: please edit and add it to your question above.

Comment: Click on the [edit] link to include the relevant code

Comment: You said you want 4 cols, each would be 3 wide, but your code is using col-4.

Comment: I corrected the code, however I stated I wanted 4 cols and would approx be 5 rows. Look like a table of sorts, but not a table.

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick:

```
<?php $result->data_seek(0); $name=$result->fetch_assoc(); ?>
    <div class="row" style="height: 40px;">
    <?php for($i=0; $i < $num; $i++){ 
            while($name=$result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="height: 40px;">
    <a href="<?php echo $site; ?>/genre-search/?Gtype=<?php echo $name['name']; ?>" title="Click to see all titles with the genre <?php echo $name['name']; ?>!"><span style="font-family: Maven Pro; font-size: 18px;"><?php echo $name['name']; ?></span></a></div>
            <?php } } if($i > 4) { echo "</div><div class='row' style='height: 40px;'>"; } ?>
```